# reversed array in C++

Tags: c++, loops

How may I reverse an array with using for loop? -without using any functions.
this is my code

```
int num, i, reversed;

cout << "enter your original array size: \n" << endl;
cin >> num;

int arr[num], arrC[num];
cout << "enter original array items: \n" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    cin >> arr[i];

cout << "your array items are: \n";
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    cout << arr[i] << endl;

cout << "index: \n";
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    cout << i << endl;

cout << "original array: \n";
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    cout << arr[i] << endl;

cout << "reversed array:" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < num; i--)
```

I stopped at this point. May you help me with it?

Comment: `int arr[num], arrC[num];` is not C++.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJM3qc2dXj4

Comment: *I stopped at this point.* -- You didn't even attempt a solution.  What is there to help with, except to post a full solution?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are almost there. Your loop:

```
cout<<"reversed array:"<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<num;i--)
```

should be

```
for(int i=num-1;i>=0;i--)
```

Answer (score 0):

Normal array in a for loop (C style):

```
char arr[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};    

for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)); i++) {
    std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Reversed array in a for loop (C style):

```
for (int i = (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: int num, i, reversed;

cout << "enter your original array size: \n" << endl;
cin >> num;

int arr[num], arr2[num];
cout << "enter original array items: \n" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    cin >> arr[i];

cout << "your array items are: \n";
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    cout << arr[i] << endl;

cout << "index: \n";
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    cout << i << endl;

cout << "original array: \n";
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    cout << arr[i] << endl;

cout << "reversed array:" << endl;
for (int i=num-1;i>=0;i--)
    cout<<arr[i]<<endl;